# Consuming ArcIMS image service in Silverlight application

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I have a vendor who has supplied a secured ArcIMS image service (with raster data) and I am trying to add in a Silverlight based application. When I try to add this as layer in ArcMap and trying to convert this into MSD, it says that this layer is not supported.  I can't really publish this map service as an msd based service. I have been trying lot of different things but haven't found the way to do this. I thought I will ask if other users have tried to do this.

My environment: ArcGIS Server 10

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Can you grab the image from the ArcIMS service via its bounding box, then add that as an Element Layer in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do this right now... I let you know if I find a solution. However I cant find any info other than Using ArcXML which, from what i gather is server side coded which doesn't work when you cant access the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since Esri Silverlight API does not contain built-in layer for consuming ArcIMS services, one option is to implement your own.

This is done by inheriting from [DynamicLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.DynamicLayer.html) class and overriding certain method, including the `GetSource` method which is responsible for fetching a map image for the current extent. See the documentation of `DynamicLayer` for a more detailed description.

For ArcIMS (general documentation [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcims/10.0/mainhelp/arcims_help.htm)), fetching a map image would involve issuing a [GET_IMAGE](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcims/10.0/mainhelp/mergedProjects/ArcXMLGuide/elements/using_get_image.htm) request against the service.

Another alternative (and maybe significantly easier) is to publish your ArcIMS service as WMS using the [ArcIMS WMS Connector](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcims/10.0/mainhelp/arcims_help.htm). You can then consume the service as WMS, which is already supported in the Silverlight API.